# vue: v-html - handle click of svg object

Tags: vuejs3, graphviz

Here's what I've achieved:
Backend:

1. parse some process flow data - Python
2. use Graphviz to render the data and create the source for svg - Python
   Frontend:
3. retrieve the SVG source as a string
4. in Vue create a  element
5. update V Html

Now, I can see the SVG displayed on my browser.

A few things I've tried but gave up on:

1. Use none Graphviz to render the flow chart

- I tried G6 dagre layout but it only works when the nodes/edges are fewer
  In my case, I got around 100 nodes

2. Use the Graphviz in js

- I tried d3-graphviz, dagre-d3, viz.js none of them work properly
  I always get syntax errors - as I'm unfamiliar with js/ts I gave up

What I want to achieve:
Each of the  elements in the SVG can respond to the event.

Is it possible? The only thing I can think about is when I get the SVG string, I then manipulate the string and insert the events such as onclick

```
vhtml.value = data["definition"];
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Yes, you can manipulate the SVG as a string - and add inline event handlers. Or you can manupulate the SVG string to assign unique IDs to each node you need to handle clicks for, and then use `addEventListener` to attach your listener(s) to each of these IDs.